# Error on Entity framework insert field not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I got Error on Entity framework insert. When I want to add records in sub table I got field not found error.
This is my main table class as below:

```
public class Rcp
    {
        public Rcp()
        {
            RcpFl  = new HashSet<RcpFiles>();
        }

        [Column("Rcp_ID")]
        public int RcpId { get; set; }
        public String RcpTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RcpFiles> RcpFl { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my sub table class:

```
 public class RcpFiles
    {
        [Key]
        public int RcpFile_Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        public virtual Rcp rcp { get; set; }
    }
```

On insert time I got error Field  **"RcpFile_Id" could not be found**.

Comment: does the subtable contain column named "RcpFile_Id"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rt2800  yes  RcpFiles has field RcpFile_Id as above code.

Comment: Why `RcpFiles` doesn't have own `Id`?

Comment: I think `RcpFile_Id` must be a foreign key and you need to put `Id` for `RcpFiles` class

Comment: @گلی you should define own ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on convention regarding property names. This is how you can specify the relationships using annotations.

```
public class Rcp
{
    public Rcp()
    {
        RcpFl  = new HashSet<RcpFiles>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("Rcp_ID")]
    public int RcpId { get; set; }

    public String RcpTitle { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(RcpFiles.rcp))]
    public virtual ICollection<RcpFiles> RcpFl { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class RcpFiles
{
    [Key]
    public int RcpFile_Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    [Column("Rcp_ID")]
    public int RcpId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RcpId))]
    public virtual Rcp rcp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have one-to-many relationship.

First you must add foreign key property to `RcpFiles` entity:

```
public class RcpFiles
    {
        [Key]
        public int RcpFile_Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        public virtual Rcp rcp { get; set; }
        public int RcpId { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you have to set configuration. You have two options to do that:

Fist is `Fluent API`:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RcpFiles> RcpFiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rcp> Rcpes{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configures one-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<RcpFiles>()
            .HasRequired<Rcp>(s => s.rcp)
            .WithMany(g => g.RcpFl)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.RcpId); 
    }
}
```

The second one is `Data annotiation`: this part explained by @brian-parker (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492496/brian-parker)

For more information you can see: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your attention Mr. @Alireza Ahmadi  Special Thanks.